# I am trying to make a program that finds the area of a circle as my first project in python. does anything know what I did wrong?

Tags: python

I have tried putting 3.14 in as a variable, and am not sure what is wrong. It always gives me the same error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/[REDACTED]/PycharmProjects/Pi/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    Mn = (n * n) * 3.14
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

The code I am using is:

```py
n = input()

Mn = (n * n) * 3.14

print(Mn)
```

Comment: Look into "casting" of a string into a float.

Comment: n=int(n) will convert n from type string to int

Comment: You want to cast to a float, not an int. Or you'll get an integer as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

the input() in the first line will return a string so any value you are giving as input for example 5 will be stored in n as a string, you can check the type of n by using type(n).

instead use int(input()) this will store the input you pass as an integer; similarly for float input you can use float(input())

to fix your issue: make these changes:

```
n = int(input())

Mn = (n * n) * 3.14

print(Mn)
```

Comment: Nothing in the question says `n` Is an integer.

Comment: yes, so just convert the string input to any numeric data type you want like int , float etc so that arithmetic operations can be performed over them

Answer (score -1):

You are multiplying a string by a string. Use `int(n) * int(n)` or `int(n) ** 2`.